# C++ properties for opaque data types

Tags: c++, stl, binary-compatibility

I am building a C++ API which needs to be extendable without recompiling the software that uses it (for lots of bad reasons). This requires opaque data types so that fields can be added to classes.  Something like

```
struct CheshireCat; // Not defined here
std::unique_ptr<CheshireCat> d_ptr;
```

But this API will have lots of simple property get/set methods that just access fields within CheshireCat.  (I do not want to hear about "encapsulation" philosophy, that is just the way that it is for this application.)

There are clever techniques that create classes like MyInt that override operators to emulate properties like

```
int & operator = (const int &i) { return value = i; }
operator int () const { return value; }
```

But I cannot see any good way of such a MyInt getting access to the CheshireCat pointer in the containing class, let alone the hidden properties within the structure.

It seems like this must be a very common problem, so I am looking for other people's clever solutions.  Possibly using some obscure macrology.

(The alternatives would be 1. Forget binary compatibility, or 2. write lots and lots of boilerplate code by hand.)

I realize that for binary compatibility new virtual methods need to be added to the end.  Mangling is compiler dependent but should be stable for a given compiler (we will ship binaries made for a specific compiler/version).

This feels like C++ 101 but I could not find anything that addressed it elegantly.  (My background is Java/.Net/Lisp where JITing solves this problem.  A C++ system that did the final compilation phases in the (DLL) linker would be excellent but sadly that is not the way it is.)

Comment: I dont see where you explained your problem with the pimpl idiom. Getters/Setters are not a problem...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get binary compatibility by exposing C++.

What you can do is expose a C interface (which is binary compatible).  That means, as you have hinted, exposing functions that deal with opaque handles (i.e. pointers).

Of course, the internals can be written in C++.

Comment: I think that in practice you can get binary compatibility provided that you use the same C++ compiler/version, opaque data types, and only ever add virtual methods to the end.  (This last requirement is odd, but C++ compilers do not seem to create linker symbols for virtual methods, just hard code the offsets.)

Comment: That is implementation dependent. I wouldn't want to depend on an implementation detail that may change in the future.